# Time series is throwing up error message

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to conduct a time series analysis based on this dataset:

```
time    POINT_Y POINT_X
00:00   106.78  207.44
00:30   106.61  207.6
01:00   103.72  208.33
01:30   102.57  207.35
02:00   102.27  206.3
02:30   101.6   206.43
03:00   100.66  206.73
03:30   101.11  206.5
04:00   100.95  206.63
04:30   102.02  206.27
05:00   105.83  207.93
05:30   106.98  207.15
06:00   107.32  206.28
06:30   108.36  204.7
07:00   107.97  203.41
07:30   107.76  202.63
08:00   107.85  201.13
08:30   107.6   198.74
```

It has been set as:

```
austriacus<-read.table("austriacus.txt",header=T).
```

The time series function: `x.ts<-ts(POINT_X,time)` is not working and is producing the following error message: `Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'POINT_X' not found`

Any ideas on this?

Comment: You should do something of the like of `ts(austracius)`. Right now, you are attempting to run `ts()` on a data frame called `POINT_X`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I need to conduct the ts() function for POINT_X against time. Is there a way to do it, similarly to this: ts(POINT_X,time)

Comment: AFAIK, `ts(austracius)` will already do that. You _cannot_ run ts on `POINT_X`, because that's a variable you haven't defined. `POINT_X` is a _column_ of dataframe `austracius`. If you type `?ts` you will see that the first argument to `ts()` should be either a matrix or a data frame! If you ONLY want the time series on `POINT_X` you can make a a new dataframe with only that, à la: `new_df <- data.frame(time=austracius$time,x=austracius$POINT_X)`. and then do simply `ts(new_df)`.

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 1):

Try the zoo and chron packages:

```
Lines <- "time    POINT_Y POINT_X
00:00   106.78  207.44
00:30   106.61  207.6
01:00   103.72  208.33
01:30   102.57  207.35
02:00   102.27  206.3
02:30   101.6   206.43
03:00   100.66  206.73
03:30   101.11  206.5
04:00   100.95  206.63
04:30   102.02  206.27
05:00   105.83  207.93
05:30   106.98  207.15
06:00   107.32  206.28
06:30   108.36  204.7
07:00   107.97  203.41
07:30   107.76  202.63
08:00   107.85  201.13
08:30   107.6   198.74
"

library(zoo)
library(chron)
to.times <- function(x) times(paste0(x, ":00"))

# z <- read.zoo("myfile", header = TRUE, FUN = to.times)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, FUN = to.times)

plot(z)
```

Comment: Not sure why you added this function and the `chron` library. He could just do `z <- zoo(df$POINT_X ,df$time)` imo, as this is the only thing he asked for

Comment: @David, That would not give a meaningful index. They would be character strings so you would not, for example, be able to subtract them, plot them on a continuous scale and do other desirable manipulations.

Comment: I agree that you wouldn't be able to subtract them (not sure if he needs it) but `plot(z)` will give you same result.

Comment: df has not been defined but if the time index is character you will get an error when plotting it.